# When should I override toString()?

Tags: java

I know that the [Javadocs says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

But when should I spend time overriding the `toString` method for my classes? Should it be one of the first things I do along with overriding `equals` and `hashCode`?  Or should I wait until it's actually needed?

I know Eclipse can auto generate `toString` methods for you, so should I just have Eclipse auto generate them once I know the fields for my class?

Comment: I rarely do this and if I do it's for debugging purposes

Comment: Since modern IDEs can generate this method for you in a moment, why not use it if you're expecting to print your object?

Comment: Ignoring the auto-generate possibility, it's up to you.  The vanilla toString just prints out the object class and a hash identifier.  If you want to use toString for diagnostic printing it's worth the effort to add your own that prints out the important fields of your object in a rational presentation.

Comment: Or, as a rule of thumb, about the third time you find yourself doing a println to print out several fields of the object, it's time to code your own toString.

Comment: Have a look at [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/ToString.html) which can generate your `toString()` method on the fly based on a single `@ToString` annotation you add to a class. This is better than Eclipse's code generation as it adjusts the code automatically after you change your class's fields.

Comment: Do it in most cases, and only for debugging/logging purposes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Josh Bloch gives a good explanation in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), in item 10.

> [...] providing a good toString implementation makes your class much more pleasant to use.

It really makes it easier to output debugging traces, or makes better logging messages, since you can use the object's string representation provided by `toString()` directly; you don't have to manually build a string that gives the information needed on the object.

As stated in the book, you should include all the interesting information in the resulting `String`. You should also document properly your method; you may document the resulting `String` format or not, but you should at least document your intent (whether the format is subject to change, or not likely to change).

In the end, it is up to you (and your company's standards) to decide if overriding it in every class should be part of your habits or not. Personally, I don't override `toString ()` in every classes, only in the ones which are most at risk of being used in a debuging trace.

Comment: +1 Most IDEs can generate a toString() for you.  I tend to create one when I think I am likely to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I would implement `toString()` method on any class that holds `human understandable non confidential data`. Ex: Transfer Object, Beans, Data Object, Wrappers. For such classes just go on to implement 'toString()' method.

Classes that represent a service, process with transient states need not implement the method.Here, You can wait until it is actually needed.

Make sure you do not expose any variables with "transient" keyword in 'toString()'!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I override it when I want to assign a default format of displaying an object, often formatting a compact/digestable display of relevant attributes.  So that I can simply, for example, display it in debug or log by doing:

```
MyClass myClsInst = new MyClass();
...
System.out.println(myClsInst);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to demonstrate in simple way.

```
package com.web.doamin;

public class User {

    String name;

    long id;

    /*@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [user = " + name + ", id="+ id + "]"; 
    }*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        System.out.println(" : user : " + user );
    }
}
```

> > If we did't Override toString() method we will get Object Hash code in sysout
> >
> > O/P **without Override toString()** method - com.web.doamin.**User@7852e922**
> >
> > if We **Override the ToString()** method we will get O/P -  **User [user = null, id=0]**

**Note** - *It is a good idea to override toString() as we get get proper output when an object is used in System.out.println();*

Answer (score 0):

In general, It's used to show or see what the object has.

For instance, Let's say there is a Student class and you created objects.

Student class has age, grade, gpa, name, country, address.

```
class Student{
    private int age;
    private int grade;
    private double gpa;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String address;

    Student(...){
       // ...
    }

    public String toString(){
        String str = "age is "+age+ ", grade is " + grade + ...
        return str;
    }
}
```

And you created A student, and B student ( and maybe more )

You just need to 'toString()' for checking its inside like this:

```
System.out.println(aStudent.toString());
System.out.println(bStudent.toString());
```

or You can just write the object name, it automatically calls 'toString()'

```
System.out.println(aStudent);
System.out.println(bStudent);
```

It removes the redundant works & faster.

Then, you will see like this:

```
Output:
age is 13, grade is 3, ...
age is 15, grade is 5, ...
```

It's useful when you see what A student or B student has when you debug.

And also, It's useful when you make your own form like JSON.

It will be easier to manipulate its data with JSON format.